# jQuery Select tables that match criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and within that table, sub tables for each entry. Each entry is the `$item`. The UI in question is a search facility that can be used to send a list of 'selected' items via ajax to a mail function. Each item being a the table with its check box selected.

However, when I click a check-box and select send, this only gets the HTML for one table, not all selected.

```
jQuery('#search-query-send').click(function(){

  jQuery('.apartment-entry:has(:checked)').each(function(){

    var content = jQuery(this).html()
    console.log(content);

  });

});
```

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knoppys/9d1pgjv8/6/)

I would like to be able to `console.log()` the HTML for each table I have selected.

Comment: fiddle is working perfectly fine for me... Add different text to boxes and you'll see it.

Comment: Cant believe i didnt notice that tbh. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got the selector correct.

```
jQuery('#search-query-send').click(function() {
    jQuery('.selectthis input:checked').each(function() {
    var content = jQuery(this).parents('table').html();
    console.log(content);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9d1pgjv8/7/

Comment: Bang Tidy. I knew i was pretty close. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry but just to take this a little further, have another look at the fiddle and youll see that Ive added my ajax function to the fold. I keep getting the error that content is not defined. i assume this is because i have two separate functions here.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291683/jquery-variable-is-not-being-populated-before-ajax-function

Answer (score 0):

You have to target selectthis class so it ll get checkbox text or values or whatever you want.

```html
$('#search-query-send').click(function(){

 $('.apartment-entry .selectthis:has(:checked)').each(function(){
  var content = $(this).text()
  console.log(content);
 });

});
```